# Do browsers have a limit to download/stream video files?

Tags: html, video, browser, limit

I've a simple html page with 9 videos, all .webm video files.

I'm using a simple html5 video  tag

```
<video controls preload="metadata"> <source src="Content/videos/somevideo.webm" type="video/webm" />
            <p>I'm sorry; your browser doesn't support HTML5 video.</p>
            <!-- You can embed a Flash player here, to play your mp4 video in older browsers -->
        </video>
```

Chrome: the first 6 videos will start streaming or at least display some metadata information like the lenght of the video and the controls, and you can press play and the video starts

Firefox: All the 9 videos load perfectly, you get the lenght of the video, you've the controls, you press play, all works.

Opera: 7 of the 9 videos will play without any problems. The other 2 videos, will not allow to b played and it show 0:00, which means it failed to download the metadata.

IE: I'm ignoring IE for now

This page is under IIS in a Windows server 2012, powered by MS Azure.

My question is, if there's a limit for each browser to download/stream videos? I'm running fiddler and I can see the videos being downloaded, 6 for chrome, or 9 for Firefox.

Comment: do the chrome devtools / console show anything interesting?

Comment: No, no errors or any clue that could explain what's happening. It was through fiddler that I was able to see that only some videos were being downloaded or all if I use Firefox.

Comment: Can you give us a little more detail? Are all of the video tags exactly the same? What are the file sizes of each of the videos? How do they differ?

Comment: They only differ in the name and size. There's no spaces in the filenames, and the size of the files are (Mb): 15, 19, 1, 32, 40, 20, 27, 21, 13.

Comment: it's a bit out of date but this table - http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/ - details some of the concurrent http limits for different browsers. If you put them on different domains (or subdomains that all map to the same server) does it help?

Comment: Thanks @Offbeatmammal. I was able to understand why the different behavior in the different browsers.